# SQL: Select a column independent of where clause

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 1000 p.Title,p.Distributor, SUM(r.SalesVolume) AS VolumeOfSales,
  CAST(SUM(r.CustomerPrice*r.SalesVolume) as decimal (18,0)) AS ValueOfSales,
  CAST (AVG(r.CustomerPrice) as decimal (18,1)) AS AvgPrice,
  p.MS_ContentType AS category ,Min(c.WeekId) AS ReleaseWeek
  from Product p
  INNER JOIN RawData r
    ON p.ProductId = r.ProductId
  INNER JOIN Calendar c
    ON r.DayId = c.DayId
  WHERE c.WeekId BETWEEN ('20145231') AND ('20145252')
    AND p.Distributor IN ('WARNER', 'TF1', 'GAUMONT')
    AND p.VODEST IN ('VOD', 'EST')
    AND p.ContentFlavor IN ('SD', 'HD', 'NC')
    AND p.MS_ExternalID1 IN ('ADVENTURE/ACTION', 'ANIMATION/FAMILY', 'COMEDY')
    AND p.MS_ContentType IN ('FILM', 'TV', 'OTHERS')
    AND r.CountryId = 1
  GROUP BY p.Title,p.Distributor,p.MS_ContentType 
  ORDER BY VolumeOfSales DESC, ValueOfSales DESC
```

I want to madify the above query so that only the column `ReleaseWeek` is independent of the where clause `WHERE c.WeekId BETWEEN ('20145231') AND ('20145252')`

The result that I dervive looks like:

```
`Title     Distributor  VolumeOfSales   ValueOfSales    AvgPrice    category    ReleaseWeek

Divergente  M6SND         94038           450095         4.0          Film      20145233`
```

However what I really want is the `ReleaseWeek` to be the first value in the column `c.WeekId` corresponding to that `Title`in the database and not the first one between `('20145231') AND ('20145252')` What is the best way to modify it? Any leads would be greatful.

Comment: It's very unclear, try to provide desired output and explain why you need It.

Comment: A subquery seems to be the most straight-forward solution. Otherwise, you'll probably have to use CTEs, and "unwrap" the release week before applying the filter and grouping.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovasn I have expalined most of the things though with the output as well. Not sure what is unclear.

Comment: @Luaan Have never truied a CTE yet but will try doing it now.

Comment: "Not sure what is unclear." - for starters, we don't have your tables nor your data. It may be clear for *you* but you have the distinct advantage of even being able to *run* the query you've shown us. Adding some basic table definitions and sample data would vastly improve the question (you could also, at the same time, remove columns and/or tables that are irrelevant to the problem at hand)